# Why do those Update statements fail using a datetime format?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-format

Given:

Query #1:

```
begin tran
UPDATE [dbo].[t] SET [mydatetime]='2011-12-25 07:00:00.000';
rollback
```

Query #2: (changing month/day)

```
begin tran
UPDATE [dbo].[t] SET [mydatetime]='2011-25-12 07:00:00.000';
rollback
```

Why does the QUERY #1 fail to run on a new installed SQL Server while query #2 runs succesfully?

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 6 Bei der Konvertierung eines
>   varchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb
>   des gültigen Bereichs.

In comparison why does Query #1 run on the old server while query #2 fails on the new server?

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The servers have different versions (2008 / 2016). And as you can see from error messages there are two different languages installed. Please don't tell me just because the language of the Sql-Server installation is different it is not able to handle different date formats?

Is this configurable?
Will I get away with uniform formats like 20150129 08:00:00.000 ?

Comment: The uniform format has `T` in between date and time, instead of space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion

Comment: And this: [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp)

Comment: You can also see the specific DATEFORMAT being used with DBCC USEROPTIONS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deal with the issue by specifying the style and doing an explicit `CONVERT()` from string to datetime rather than an implicit conversion. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

`UPDATE dbo.t SET mydatetime = CONVERT('2011-12-25 07:00:00.000', 121)`

Comment: I ended up using the SET LANGUAGE command for workaround to handle the update statements that come in and will change them to use ISO format in the long run. However thanks for taking care.