# How to correct SQL-Server installation with wrong language?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016, setup

What is the best way to re-install a SQL Server that was installed using a wrong language without losing any configuration?

- Should I install a second instance parallel to the default instance - here I do not know if this is anyhow possible at all if using a different language?
- Or should I install a second installation of Sql Server (as if it were two different Versions)?
- Alternatively I could of course uninstall the old and install a new Sql Server using the correct language.

Independent of the way to go, as you can imagine, I definitely want to avoid doing all the maintenance work for creation of Logins, Users, Permissions, Alerts, Operators, Jobs etc. again. Is there a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: So you are saying you have chosen wrong collation setting for the SQL Server ?

Comment: No, the wrong language. A German SQL Version was installed. This causes problems with SQL Statements coming in. Please read: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154978/why-do-those-update-statements-fail-using-a-datetime-format

Comment: Have you tried just setting the regional settings in Windows to English? (Date / Time / Keyboard) But I would recommend having an English Windows Server and an English SQL Server installation any time. Stuck with German / German at the moment. You might be able to backup the master/msdb databases and reinstall SQL Server and then resetore the master and msdb database over the new installation. You would then have an English SQL Server running on a German Windows Server. Never tried it myself.

Comment: BTW [Installations of different language versions of SQL Server instances on the same computer are not supported.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144258(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Had same thoughts and made some spikes - but with backup/restore of master I ran into new trouble. The solution below is very straight forward and working in my case so I will go for that and hold on until - hopefully not - new problems may happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days with SQL Server 6.4, I would say that you would have to uninstall and then re-install.  But SQL Server has gotten better since then.  So try changing it with the code below.  But if you have any problems in the next 2 months, uninstall and re-install.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190682.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

Comment: So you are telling me that all that matters is the language of a login's session that is by default derived from the installation language and not the installation language itself!? Holy good that I asked here....! That saves a lot of work... => Will the already derived default language of a login also get changed as soon I change the default lang of the instance?

Comment: The answer is no. But however, your answer is great.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done from the SSMS GUI.  Right click on the instance in object explorer and go to properties.

From there navigate to the Advanced page.

There is a drop down item there for Default Language.

Alternatively, if you know the language code you can do it via tsql

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 0 ; 
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

where 0  is English in this case.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190682.aspx

You may also need to update or change the default language of logins via their properties page.